# Grails GORM MongoDB. Issue with parent model classes

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

**Background**: I am using the GORM plugin for MongoDB in Grails.

**Problem**:Say that I have two domain classes A and B. B extends A. If I execute B.save() the plugin will create a collection named A in MongoDB. What am I supposed to do to get the plugin to create the collection B?

Many Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It should create collection B in the database.
Can you provide more info, definition of A and B classes?